# Equalize the range of the values in legends for multiple ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a huge data frame with multiple columns that I would like to make multiple tsne plot based on two first columns and colored by other variables in each plot. Here is a sample of my data frame like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
 ~NE1,  ~NE2,   ~A, ~B,
4.179,  10.506, 1.247,  7.540,
-7.544, 2.877,  1.265,  7.296,
1.485,  -37.57, 1.254, 6.173,
4.412,  -32.117,    1.185,  6.221,
-10.403,    31.718, 1.259,  7.607,
9.283,  8.213,  1.250,  7.682,)
```

I would like to have same scale limits for all of the plot but I don't know how to equalize the range od legend in all plots. I used this code:

```
p1<-ggplot(dat,  aes(x = NE1, y = NE2, color = A)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.8) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_color_gradientn("A", 
                        colours = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")))(50))

p2<-ggplot(dat,  aes(x = NE1, y = NE2, color = B)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.8) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_gradientn("B", 
                        colours = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")))(50))
grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with the wonderful `patchwork` package:

```r
library(patchwork)

p1<-ggplot(dat,  aes(x = NE1, y = NE2, color = A)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.8) +
  theme_bw()  
  
p2<-ggplot(dat,  aes(x = NE1, y = NE2, color = B)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.8) +
  theme_bw()

p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect") & 
  scale_color_gradientn("AB", 
                        colours = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, 
                                                  name = "Spectral")))(50), 
                        limits = range(dat$NE2))
```

If you'd like to have a separate legend for each plot:

```
p1 + p2 & 
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, 
                                                                  name = "Spectral")))(50), 
                        limits = c(-10,30))
```

Comment: Thanks @mharinga but this gives one legend for all plots. As I said I would like to draw multiple plots and specify the color of each plot according to the value of a variable. The problem I have is that I want the range of values in all legend be the same to make it more comparable

Comment: I updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes @mharinga very nice. Thanks a lot